# What is the reason behind high frequency output from LSTM model?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, lstm

Following is the time history response of my input features, which has relatively low frequency component
[image]
My LSTM network architecture is as follows:

```matlab
layers = [
    sequenceInputLayer(size(X_train{1}, 1)) % Input Features (F)
    lstmLayer(x.num_hidden_units_1, 'OutputMode', 'sequence')
    tanhLayer
    dropoutLayer(0.05)
    lstmLayer(x.num_hidden_units_2, 'OutputMode', 'sequence')
    dropoutLayer(0.05)
    tanhLayer
    fullyConnectedLayer(x.num_layers_ffnn)
    tanhLayer
    fullyConnectedLayer(1)
];
```

During the training, my network predictions are plotted with the target output as follows
[image]
The network output has a very high frequency output on the valildation data, however when the model is used to predict the test data, it is giving a flat line.
[image]
The two major concerns for me are:

1. Why the LSTM network is giving high frequency output even when the input features have relatively low frequency?
2. During the training when the model has high frequency, why is it giving a flat line during testing?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Consider using a code block to make your architecture a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question to make it more clear